# ASP.NET Core 2.1: Add client certificate to registered typed HTTP clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I introduced the new way of ASP.NET Core 2.1 to create/register HTTP clients in my application like described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/28/asp-net-core-2-1-preview1-introducing-httpclient-factory/). It's worked fine until I needed to add an client certificate to my typed HTTP client.

I did many researches and I didn't find a way to do it..

I expected something like that:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IMonitoringService, MonitoringService>(
            client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.Configuration.GetSection("ServiceEndpoints:Monitoring").Get<ServiceEndpointConfiguration>().Endpoint);
                client.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(/* ... */)); // Error: `ClientCertificates` doesn't exists.
            });
```

Or like that:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IMonitoringService, MonitoringService>(
                client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(this.Configuration.GetSection("ServiceEndpoints:Monitoring").Get<ServiceEndpointConfiguration>().Endpoint))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler(
                () =>
                {
                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(/* ... */));
                    return handler; // Error: Expected return type is `DelegatingHandler`.
                });
```

But such ways doesn't exists..

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try using `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` instead of of `AddHttpMessageHandler`?  See [Certificate error when configuring HttpClientFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989872/certificate-error-when-configuring-httpclientfactory)

Comment: Nice it's exactly what I want! Make an answer of it and I'm gonna approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your experience that `AddHttpMessageHandler` is required to return a type of `DelegatingHandler` as this function is used to extend the request pipeline.  In order to create an `HttpClientHandler` with a client certificate attached, you should instead use `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` to create and return the configured instance of `HttpClientHandler`.